# React Native can't find image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a file where I store some information in json format :

```
export const dummyData = [
    {
        title: 'BOAT DETAILS', url :'/home/chloe/Desktop/App/app/component/schema.jpg', 
        description: 'xxxxxxx', id : 1
    }, 
    {
        title: 'TUTORIALS', url :'/home/chloe/Desktop/App/app/component/tuto.png', 
        description: 'yyyyyyyyy', id : 2
    }, 
]
```

This information is called in a component named CarouselItem.js :

```
const CarouselItem = ({item}) => {
    const url = item.url
    return (
        <View style= {styles.cardView}>
            <Image style = {styles.image} source={require(url)} />
            <View style = {styles.textView}>
                <Text style = {styles.itemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style={ styles.imageDescription}>{item.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

My problem is that when I try to pass the url (so the item.url) it says the following error:

[image]

The pictures do exist in my app because if I do : source={require('/home/chloe/Desktop/App/app/component/schema.jpg')} then it works and if I do url = '/home/chloe/Desktop/App/app/component/schema.jpg' it still does not work.

So what amI doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you already tried to log it to the console to see if it is not undefined?

Comment: Yes I did and it is not undefined and the type is String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the uri method

```
<Image style = {styles.image} source={{ uri: url }} />
```

Edit:

I foud this post, and based on your error, I think it will be useful [Post](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths)

Comment: if it fails, tell me, I'll try to search more and help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load a **local** image you may use something like this:

```
<Image source={require('./path/to/image.png')} />
```

But if you're reading an **external URL**, try this:

```
<Image source={{ uri: external_url }} />
```

PS: when using external URL you must declare image's width and height. And for local images consider creating an assets folder inside your project.